# Use numerical IDs of text boxes to initialize DoDataExchange?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, variables, mfc, resources

So I have close to 300 variables (just right now), and I have numerically ordered their IDs in Resource.h so it's:

```
#define IDC_BOX1     1
#define IDC_BOX2     2
#define IDC_BOX3     3
#define IDC_BOX4     4
```

etc. My question involves the DoDataExchange that I'm performing for each different dialog that I have that contains all of these variables. I REALLY don't want to go through doing the following for each variable:

```
DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX1, m_nBox1);
DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX2, m_nBox2);
DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX3, m_nBox3);
DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX4, m_nBox4);
```

because that's just ridiculous.

How can I do something along the same lines as this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < **totalVariables**; i++)
     DDX_CText(pDX, **nameByIdInResourceFile(i)**, **indexOfVariableNameInArray**;
```

I'm sure this is possible, I just don't know what the function might be that pulls the IDC_... variable names by their ID number. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mark Ransom's answer is great.  I do exactly what he suggests, but I have one other thing I do as well.  During my app's startup (guarded by an #ifdef DEBUG), I have some code that verifies that all of my IDs are in consecutive numerical order.  That way, I can be sure that someone (likely me in the future) doesn't come along and add an out-of-numerical-sequence ID.

Comment: Good idea, Randy. Thanks for the tip. It is definitely something I'll have to put in, because that could be a pain for people to deal with in the future.

Comment: How do you verify all of your IDs without listing them out individually? That conflicts with the point of the original question.

Comment: In my case, I have a bunch of sets of 4 control IDs, so I use a bit of macro magic to do it.  That likely won't work in @Jon's case, especially given that his ID names aren't sequentially numbered.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've gone to the trouble of creating your resource IDs consecutively and in order, it's easy to go through all of them in the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (IDC_BOX300-IDC_BOX1); i++)
     DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX1+i, ...
```

Naturally this will fail if someone comes along and adds IDC_BOX301 and doesn't put it in the sequence properly, so be careful!

The simplest solution for the variable names is to replace the individual variables with an array.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= (IDC_BOX300-IDC_BOX1); i++)
     DDX_CText(pDX, IDC_BOX1+i, m_nBoxes[i]);
```

Comment: Well I kind of misrepresented that. I was just giving dummy code before. The resource IDs are not numerical like that...their ID numbers are. So in reality, they're like "IDC_MAIN_LENGTH" and "IDC_MAIN_MAX_WIDTH" etc. But, all of my variables are numerically ordered in the Resource.h file, so I was hoping there was a GetResourceById() function that I could use to just iterate through the ID numbers of all my resources to pull the IDC_MAIN_LENGTH...etc. names. Then I would create an array of my variable names and just iterate through that...

Comment: Almost like the opposite of GetDlgCtrlId() which takes in the IDC_VARIABLE_NAME and returns the ID number...I want the opposite.

Comment: @Jon, I think you have a basic misunderstanding of how things work. The DDX functions take the ID number as a parameter, and the names are merely handy representations of those numbers. It is not necessary to use the names at all, except for knowing what the first and last ID numbers are. As for GetDlgCtrlID, it takes a window handle as input, not a name.

Comment: Wow, so I can just do a for loop with the ID numbers then? Ugh. That's far easier. I will try that. Thank you for the help, Mark!